# Filter the results of a query using conditions in asp.net with entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, entity-framework

I want to know how many people are in a especify local, using entry and exit validation of this person. If he has entered in the local, then he will generate a transaction with a `TrCode = "C0"`. when he comes out of the place, he will generate a `TrCode = "CI"`. There are other types of TrCode, but it is useless for this kind o validation. i have a query that returns to me this result down bellow:

```
        var query = from a in context.CardDB
                    join c in context.tblTransaction on a.CardNo equals c.CardNo
                    where c.TrCode == "C0" || c.TrCode == "CI"
                    where c.TrSiteCode == sitecode
                    select c;
```

Now I have all the rows that have the TrCode == "C0" or TrCode == "CI". But the result gives me all the transactions that the employers(CardDB) did. So the result gives a lot of transactions made of different employers. Sometimes some employer make 2 or even 3 transcations like, when he arrives and when he goes out for lunch, then he cames back etc.

I have to show in a grid just the employers that have in general count more transactions `TrCode == "C0"` than `TrCode == "CI"`. So, what i have to do to count the transcations of only the employers with the same ID, and, when showing it in the grid, show just a row of this employers and not all the rows.

Since already, Thank you!

Comment: What columns / fields are in CardDB ?

Comment: there are ID, CardNo(that i use as a foreign key in tblTransaction table) and TrSiteCode that i use to filtrate the employer's workplace

Comment: I am not good with 'SQL style' LINQ, especially against a DB model that isn't in front of me. But fundamentally you need to group by TrSiteCode and TrCode, and then use Sum. That will then give you three columns - TrSiteCode, TrCode and Sum.

Answer (score 0):

```
var queryNumberC0 = query.Where(c => c.TrCode == "C0").Select(c => c.ID).GroupBy(c => c.Value).ToList();
var queryNumberC1 = query.Where(c => c.TrCode == "C1").Select(c => c.ID).GroupBy(c => c.Value).ToList();
```

And to get the number of the ID **y** (Key is the ID of the customer):

```
int y = [Customer's ID];
int temp = queryNumberC0.Find(c => c.Key == y);
```

You don't have to specifie the ToList() at the end of the query, do what you want with the result. I just find it easier to browse